# NSInvalidArgumentException || Unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, invalidargumentexception

I have a tableView and I create a Button on one cell.

```
UIButton *deleteGroupButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [deleteGroupButton setFrame:CGRectMake(218, 12, 40, 60)];
    [deleteGroupButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteGroupButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

When I click to button, an Exception occur with that message:

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Group deleteGroup:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a8afc0' "

And that is my deleteGroupButtonClicked method

```
- (void) deleteGroupButtonClicked: (id) sender {    

    Groups *tmpGroups = [[Group alloc] init];
    NSInteger tmp = appDelegate.selectedGroupId;
    [tmpGroups deleteGroup:tmp];
    [tmpGroups release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have something slightly odd in your deleteGroupButtonClicked: method,

You have a object of class `Groups` but you are alloc'ing an object of class `Group`.  I am guessing `Groups` is a collection of `Group` objects.  In which case a `deleteGroup:` method would only exist in the `Groups` class.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can not see this is a problem,I change it but the problem not solved. Solving the problem by changing the parameter " appDelegate.selectedGroupId " sent the same view I conducted in the different methods.

sorry my bad english, thanks again.

Comment: Can you post your Groups class definition and I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your deleteGroupButtonClicked method with the following:

```
- (void) deleteGroupButtonClicked: (id) sender 
{    

Groups *tmpGroups = [[Groups alloc] init];
NSInteger tmp = appDelegate.selectedGroupId;
[tmpGroups deleteGroup:tmp];
[tmpGroups release];
}
```

Comment: Earlier you have used: 
Groups *tmpGroups = [[Group alloc] init]; 
now 

Groups *tmpGroups = [[Groups alloc] init];

Groups/Group is the difference